# Bing GeocodeService userState usage as custom additional parameter

Tags: windows-phone-7, request, parameter-passing, geocode, bing-maps

In my Windows Phone 7.1 application I have to send a request that consumes Bing geocoding services (using the address: http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc/mex, **without** setting the option `Always generate message contracts` in my Service Reference Settings).

My request is made in this way:

```
BingMapGeoCodeService.GeocodeRequest request = new BingMapGeoCodeService.GeocodeRequest();

request.Options = new BingMapGeoCodeService.GeocodeOptions()
{
    Filters = new ObservableCollection<BingMapGeoCodeService.FilterBase>()
    {
        new BingMapGeoCodeService.ConfidenceFilter() { MinimumConfidence = BingMapGeoCodeService.Confidence.High}
    }
};

request.Credentials = ( ...my credentials... )

request.Address = new BingMapGeoCodeService.Address()
{
    AddressLine = String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) ? null : address.Trim(),
    Locality = String.IsNullOrEmpty(city) ? null : city.Trim(),
    PostalCode = String.IsNullOrEmpty(zipCode) ? null : zipCode.Trim()
};
```

...now I have to send my async request, in this way:

```
geocodeServiceClient.GeocodeAsync(request);
```

It all works fine, but I have a little problem (of course there a lot of workarounds...but I would like to do it in the best way!): I want to send, in my request, an additional parameter (in my case it's just a `Guid` identifier, but also a `String` value would be ok!) that I would use when I get the response from the server (I need it for another internal check):

```
private void geocodeServiceClient_GeocodeCompleted(object sender, BingMapGeoCodeService.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // HERE I WANT TO GET BACK MY VALUE, TO CHECK IT!  

    var geoResult = (from r in e.Result.Results
                     orderby (int)r.Confidence ascending
                     select r).FirstOrDefault();

    ... some more logic here ...
}
```

I searched around but, also because (in my opinion) of a lack of documentation, I found out this additional parameter of the `GeocodeAsync()` method:

```
geocodeServiceClient.GeocodeAsync(request, userState);
```

Can I use this parameter as a custom additional parameter for my request?

Is it the correct way to pass an extra parameter to third-part services?

In case it's not good to do so: what's the meanining and the usage of this overload?

And why is it called so (I mean *userState*)?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my own way: userState parameter is what I was searching for.

Follow this question about WCF Services:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prvn_131971/chapter-33-advanced-web-services/