# C# passing extra parameters to an event

Tags: c#

I want to pass three extra parameters to the event :

```
geocodeService.GeocodeCompleted += new EventHandler<GeocodeService.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs>(geocodeService_GeocodeCompleted);
```

The parameters are

- `int id`
- `string color`
- `double heading`

  ```
  private void Geocode(string strAddress, int waypointIndex, int id, string color, double heading)
  {


      // Create the service variable and set the callback method using the GeocodeCompleted property.
      GeocodeService.GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new GeocodeService.GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");

      // NEED TO PASS id, color, heading TO THIS EVENT HANDLER
      geocodeService.GeocodeCompleted += new EventHandler<GeocodeService.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs>(geocodeService_GeocodeCompleted);

      GeocodeService.GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new GeocodeService.GeocodeRequest();
      geocodeRequest.Credentials = new Credentials();
      geocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = ((ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider)BingMap.CredentialsProvider).ApplicationId;
      geocodeRequest.Query = strAddress;
      geocodeService.GeocodeAsync(geocodeRequest, waypointIndex);
  }


  private void geocodeService_GeocodeCompleted(object sender, GeocodeService.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
      GeocodeResult result = null;

      if (e.Result.Results.Count > 0)
      {
          result = e.Result.Results[0];
          if (result != null)
          {
              // this.ShowMarker(result);
              this.ShowShip(result);


          }
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: Where is the event raised? I suspect in the `GeocodeAysnc` method, is there any way we can see this method?

Comment: @Solo did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you can extend GeocodeService.GeocodeServiceClient adding those properties and then use the sender argument in the event method geocodeService_GeocodeCompleted:

```
var service = (GeocodeService.GeocodeServiceClient) sender;
```

The quick and dirty(IMHO) version is to use lambda expression:

[Pass parameter to EventHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644253/c-sharp-pass-parameter-to-eventhandler)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `GeocodeCompletedEventArgs` extends `AsyncCompletedEventArgs`. `AsyncCompletedEventArgs` has the property `UserState` which can be used to store state information for asynchronous events. This state is usually passed as a parameter to the method that raises the event.

See this question for more information: [Bing GeocodeService userState usage as custom additional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176217/bing-geocodeservice-userstate-usage-as-custom-additional-parameter)

Comment: i don't agree with your answer because UserState should be used to unique identify the asynchronous task and not to pass data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.userstate.aspx